# Show bar graph by MySQL SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, charts

I'm trying to practice Javascript and these bar graphs that are connected to my MySql database. However, I can't get the result from `"SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name"` using a javascript bar graph. For now, with these codes I'm going to post, it shows the 2 categories successfully, however the bars/counter won't show in which it supposed to show how many are "Completed" and how many are "On-going". Here's the screenshot of my present code:

[image: IMAGE OF THE GRAPH]

And here's my database code:

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
$sqlQuery = "SELECT con_stat, COUNT(*) FROM con_tab GROUP BY con_stat";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And here's the javascript code in which, I guess has a missing function or code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        showGraph();
    });


    function showGraph()
    {
        {
            $.post("data.php",
            function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                var category = [];
                var counts = [];

                for (var i in data) {
                    category.push(data[i].con_stat);
                    counts.push(data[i].count);
                }

                var chartdata = {
                    labels: category,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Completed and On-going',
                            backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                            borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                            hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                            hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                            data: counts
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");

                var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chartdata
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There would be a problem with the "counts.push(data[i].count);"

Comment: I think so too.. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to solve it. :(

Comment: what's the value of console.log(data);?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but to me this: `foreach ($result as $row)  {  $data[] = $row;  }` looks like you are only getting the last row into data.

Comment: Are you sure, that you getting more than one row in your result?

Comment: @PalleDue, no, `$data[] = …` adds a new element to $data every time, because of the `[]` appended at the end.

Comment: @04FS: Thanks. As I said I don't know PHP ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PHP code there are a couple of things which look incorrect or are missing steps. You should assign an alias to the `count(*)` so that the javascript can actually find it ( `data[i].count` etc ) and you should `fetch` the records

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");

/* assign an alias to count(*) */ 
$sqlQuery = "SELECT con_stat, COUNT(*) as `count` FROM con_tab GROUP BY con_stat";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);

$data = array();

/* fetch the records */
while( $rs=$result->fetch_assoc() ) $data[]=$rs;

mysqli_close( $conn );
echo json_encode( $data );
```